# How do I read and understand the build path cycle in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Eclipse gives me this error in one of my projects:

> One or more cycles were detected in the build path of project 'a'. The paths towards the cycle and cycle are:
> a->{b, c, d}
> a->{e, b, f}

where a-f are projects in the workspace.

I don't see a cycle here so I can't solve it. How do I read and understand this error message?

Comment: What language is it about? Is that the actual full message?

Comment: @nitind Java, but this is an Eclipse error not a compiler error

Comment: The same here. I even wrote a program to analyze the dependencies in .classpath and .project, and it did not find a circle. For me, the error message is not useable either. Eclipse is 2022-09